# To avoid using API, can't I just write to the Google Drive folder? How do I find it?

Tags: .net, wpf, google-drive-api

I am developing an app to create a file that then needs to be available on iPad.  I'd like to be able to use Google Drive (as well as iCloud, OneDrive).

I've been dreading using the API for this -- why do I have to?  Can't I just write to the Google Drive folder and let it sync?

Comment: If you have permissions to write to a synced folder without using any API, then yes.

Comment: I understand that you want to use Drive without touching its API or browser interface. If that is correct, could you please clarify how you want to approach the interaction? [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) could be useful in this situation, would it be a valid fix for you?